# PhpStorm + Angular Material 2, Flex layout plugin. Only allows flex attributes with breakpoint suffixes

Tags: angular, plugins, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to get PhpStorm set up to develop in Angular 2 with Angular Flex Layout. I have installed the plugin "[Angular Material 2, Flex layout 1, Teradata Covalent 1 & Material icon live templates](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9490-angular-material-2-flex-layout-1-teradata-covalent-1--material-icon-live-templates/update/32722)" but it only allows the flex attributes with the breakpoint suffixes, ie it will allow:

```
fxLayout.xl="column"
```

But it will **not** allow

```
fxLayout="column"
```

See screenshot:

[image]

I am not building a responsive app and have no need for breakpoints, and the [Angular Flex docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API) clearly show examples without them. That seems fairly ridiculous if the plugin forces you to use them. Any way around this? I'm new to PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

OK, read a bit more and my solution is to manually add these attributes in the relevant section in PhpStorm's settings under Editor > Inspections. See screenshot:

[image]